# What is the return type of a method querying MySQL with Join clause?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, servlets, arraylist

I know this might be a basic question and I couldn't find the answer most likely because I didn't how to make one.
Anyway, let's say you have this method

```
public static ***Student,Teacher?*** getStudent(int idStudent) {
    Student student = new Student() ; 
    Teacher teacher = new Teacher() ; 
    
    try { 
        Connection con=DB.getCon() ; 
        java.sql.PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select s.StudentName, s.StudentNumber,t.teacherName,t.teacherMail from student s INNER JOIN teacher t ON s.idClass = t.idClass ") ; 
        ps.setInt(1,idStudent) ; 
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery() ; 
        while(rs.next()) { 
            
            student.setStudentName(rs.getString(1)) ; 
            student.setStudentNumber(rs.setInt(2)) ; 
            teacher.setTeacherName(rs.setString(3)) ; 
            teacher.setTeacherMail(rs.setString(4)) ; 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e) ; }
    ***// return studdent ?;*** 
}
```

The same thing if I'm going to return a List<Student+Teacher> what is the type that should be returned.
Thank you

Comment: What will be the relation between student and teacher here? Will it be one teacher many students or one student many teachers? You should create an object reflecting that.

Comment: Thank you ! Both answers helped me understand. I'll create a custom object with params corresponding to the solicited columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach seeing your code above would be to create a custom object with all ur required param . Then set those param and return the list of the custom object